# Other than updating to Windows Phone 8.1, what is in the Nokia Cyan Update?

Tags: lumia, update

Nokia has started rolling out its "Cyan" update. Is there anything in this update other than updating the operating system to 8.1?

Comment: Yes, besides nice update to calendar it brings considerable amount of LAG to user interface/camera/etc. I'm using cyan almost a month, and still remember how snappy was phone before update.

Answer (score 4):

[Lumia Cyan](http://www.wpcentral.com/lumia-cyan) provides additional experiences to Windows Phone 8.1

It contains drivers for new hardware, and APIs to access them as well. It enables [Living Images](http://www.wpcentral.com/tag/living-images) and new features in the Creative Studio editing app. There are Bluetooth LE profiles and additional battery savings.

Cameras with specific hardware will be able to use the new [Nokia Sensor Core SDKs](http://www.wpcentral.com/tag/sensorcore), as well as enable [Miracast](http://www.wpcentral.com/miracast-and-windows-phone-81-hands-video) support.

Compatibility with additional accessories like [Treasure tags](http://www.wpcentral.com/lumia-icon-81-preview-treasure-tag-cyan) is in the Cyan update as well as additional [display](http://www.wpcentral.com/nokias-cyan-update-will-let-you-further-tweak-brightness-levels-your-liking) and [audio controls](http://www.wpcentral.com/nokia-lumia-930-feature-dolby-digital-audio-recording).

Comment: No fine tune brightness options?

Comment: @Vitor Check the first link, I didn't have time to enumerate every feature and link.

Answer (score 2):

[Paul Thurrott's wrote a post recently pertaining to this](http://winsupersite.com/windows-phone/here-comes-windows-phone-81-and-lumia-cyan):

> Nokia Lumia Cyan is a bit less well-understood. In [Nokia Lumia "Cyan" Firmware Update to Improve Imaging](http://winsupersite.com/windows-phone/nokia-lumia-cyan-firmware-update-improve-imaging), I wrote about the one area of improvement that Microsoft Mobile/Nokia has gone public about so far. But in a new post this week, the firm provides a few more details.
>
> Those imaging improvements will improve apps like Nokia Camera, Creative Studio and Storyteller, the firm says, and each will be updated separately. (My understanding is that these apps don't come "with" the firmware update but are rather still separate downloads.
>
> Nokia Camera gets "a simplified user interface with one-tap access to edit and share pictures, and full-resolution zooming and re-framing," Microsoft Mobile notes, and you'll be able to access Creative Studio 6 directly from the app's Camera Roll too. This updated app is available now.
>
> The updated Creative Studio 6 will be available soon and will include new filters and image enhancement tools.
>
> The updated Storyteller app, which I think is available now, turns your best photos into short videos that can easily be shared with others.
>
> Cyan will also include a new Nokia Device Hub that keeps track of when and where you last used Nokia accessories with your handset. The goal here, apparently, is to "help you track down a missing accessory," which is a little goofy. But it also provides handset-specific accessory recommendations. (I see Device Hub on my own phones, so it's not clear if this is an updated version or whatever.)

Answer (score 0):

Lumia Cyan is Windows Phone 8.1 + some additional updates for Lumia phones only.

**EDIT :** Lumia additional updates are quite minor. It mainly concerns imaging software and applications. Obviously there are also some WP 8.1 adaptations and optimizations for Lumia phones.

The only official information I found were [here](http://www.nokia.com/global/windows-phone-cyan-update/) (what matters is that MS says, not what so-called leakers say on the Internet). The page mainly deals with Windows Phone 8.1 new features. Those last represent about 95% of the Lumia Cyan update, do not delude yourself. Usually, Lumia additional updates has got much more new features than WP updates but it is not the case at all with Lumia Cyan. The last 5% are better imaging, Living Images (a 2 seconds video before a photo shoot to have a better photo) and quick links to Nokia Creative Studio too.

That's allmost all. There are not any single major features in Lumia Cyan. All is in the huge Windows Phone 8.1. If Microsoft Mobile had published a changelog for Lumia Cyan, it would have been like this:

> - *Living Images*.
> - *Quick links to Creative Studio.*
> - *Bugfixes and other improvements*.

Comment: Answer updated with answers about the Lumia Cyan changelog.

Comment: Lumia Cyan is not Windows Phone 8.1. 8.1 is the OS and Cyan is the firmware. They happen to be bundled together, but that's largely a coincidence.